# How do I handle initialize method on a triangle class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a triangle with three sides and three angles. s1, a1, s2, a2, s3, a3 and I want to initialize this via triangle.new

Here is the code that I have:

```
module Triangle
class Triangle
  attr_accessor :s1, :a1, :s2, :a2, :s3, :a3

  def initialize(s1, a1, s2, a2, s3, a3)
    @s1 = s1
    @a1 = a1
    .
    .
    .
  end
end
end
```

Now here is my problem. I want to be able to handle triangles with missing angles or sides. I've played around with optional arguments, but if you give me four numbers, I don't know which ones are sides and which ones are angles. Is the best thing to do is require six numbers and just call them using something like `triangle.new(5,nil,6,nil,9,nil)`? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just pass a hash of options to the initialize method, like so:

```
class Triangle
  attr_accessor :s1, :a1, :s2, :a2, :s3, :a3

  def initialize(options)
    @s1 = options[:s1]
    @a1 = options[:a1]
    .
    .
    .
  end
end
```

With this you can do:

```
Triangle.new({:s1 => 5, :s2 => 6, :s3 => 9})
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't smell like my code did. I knew I was doing something wrong.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 the calling line could be this: `Triangle.new(s1: 5, s2: 6, s3: 9, a1: 7, a3: 0)` using the new hash passing syntax.

Comment: The `if` conditions are unnecessary. If the value for `:a1` does not exist, `options[:a1]` will return `nil`, and assigning that to `@a1` will have the same effect as not assigning `@a1`, in which case a `@a1` call will return `nil`.

Comment: @sawa thanks for your (tired )eyes-opening comment - I editted the answer accordingly